# Expectation of convergence in probability to a constant

Tags: probability

I'm trying to prove whether if $X_{n} \overset{p}\to a$ where $a$ is a constant, does this mean that $E[X_{n}] \to a$ always?

Comment: "$X_{n} \to a$" in what sense? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables

Comment: @leonbloy edited, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Let the probability space be $((0, 1], \mathscr{B}(0, 1], \lambda)$ and define
\begin{align}
X_n(\omega) = nI_{(0, 1/n)}(\omega)
\end{align}
Then $X_n$ converges to $0$ everywhere. But $E[X_n] = 1 \not\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

To take limit to the expectation, besides convergence in probability, you also need some regularity conditions such as uniform integrability or the existence of dominating function.

---

For any $\omega \in (0, 1]$, for all $n > \lfloor 1/\omega \rfloor + 1$, since $\omega > 1/n$, $X_n(\omega) \equiv 0$, hence $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) = 0$.

Since the probability measure is the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, by definition of $X_n$, it follows that
$$E[X_n] = \int_0^1 X_n(\omega) d\omega = \int_0^{1/n} n d\omega = n \times \frac{1}{n} = 1.$$

Comment: why does $X_{n}$ converge to 0 everywhere? And why is $E[X_{n}]$ value = 1?

Comment: @Auser I added more details for you.

Comment: In another (more informal) formulation: let $X_n=n$ with prob. $1/n$, $0$ otherwise. Then $X_{n} \overset{p}\to 0$ but $E[X_n]=1$ $\forall n$

Comment: @leonbloy thanks for that simpler example

Comment: @Auser Actually it's the same  :-)

Comment: @leonbloy oh, I see that now. Just stated more informally then :)